# Object being "not final" acting strange

Tags: plsql

I have the following code:

```
create or replace type t_gib force as object (
  fld number,
  member function f return number
) not final;
/

declare
  type tab_bin is table of pls_integer index by pls_integer;

  type t_rec is record (
    f1        t_gib
   ,f2        tab_bin
   ,f3        tab_bin
   ,f4        t_gib
  );
  --
  l_rec       t_rec;
begin
  l_rec.f2(1) := 5;
  l_rec.f2(2) := 7;
  l_rec.f3(1) := 9;
  --
  dbms_output.put_line(l_rec.f2.count          || '-' || l_rec.f3.count);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_rec.f2(l_rec.f2.last) || '-' || l_rec.f3(l_rec.f3.last));
end;
/
```

This does not compile. But it compiles if I remove the `not final`.

Additionally it also compiles if I just re-arrange the record thus

```
  type t_rec is record (

    f2        tab_bin
   ,f3        tab_bin
   ,f4        t_gib
   ,f1        t_gib
  );
```

Does anybody have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Do you mind to tell us the compilation error ?

Comment: In 11.2.0.3 it compiles OK but fails with a runtime error, `ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection` when you attempt to access `l_rec.f2.count`. That is indeed strange, as l_rec.f2 has nothing to do with the object type. (btw you can simplify the example a bit - your record only needs `f1` and `f2` and one assignment, then `dbms_output.put_line(l_rec.f2.count);` gives the error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your have some other business going on there as your example works fine (11gR2). Please see the full working example below. I guess you should also drop `force` and `not final` keywords unless you know what you're doing, but they should have no effect in this example.

**Test type**

```
create or replace type foo_t force is object (
 m_f number
,member function f return number
) not final;
/
show errors

create or replace type body foo_t is
  member function f return number is
  begin
    return m_f;
  end;
end;
/
show errors
```

**Example use**

```
declare
  type int_int_hash_t is table of pls_integer index by pls_integer;

  type bar_t is record (
    b1 foo_t
   ,b2 int_int_hash_t
   ,b3 int_int_hash_t
   ,b4 foo_t
  );

  v_bar bar_t;
begin
  v_bar.b1    := foo_t(1);
  v_bar.b2(2) := 2;
  v_bar.b3(3) := 3;
  v_bar.b4    := foo_t(4);

  dbms_output.put_line(v_bar.b1.f);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_bar.b2(2));
  dbms_output.put_line(v_bar.b3(3));
  dbms_output.put_line(v_bar.b4.f);
end;
/
```

**Results**

```
SQL> @so62.sql
No errors.
1
2
3
4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```